# I coded in a button in xcode's viewcontroller.swift - How do I get it to show in storyboard?

Tags: xcode, swift, facebook, storyboard

Specifically, I coded in facebook's login button into my view controller file.  However it does not show up in storyboard.  I know how to make a button in storyboard and then connect in code with right click drag, but when I try this to back into connecting the two and create my IBOutlet, I seem to just be creating two different login buttons.

How do I get the facebook login button to show up in storyboard?

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate
{    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() == nil)
        {
            print("Not logged in..")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Logged in..")
        }

        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        loginButton.center = self.view.center
        loginButton.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }
```

Comment: drag a view onto your storyboard and give the classname as FBSDKLoginButton

Comment: this is where I run into the issue where I end up having two buttons.  As the code currently exists, I have one button, it just isn't visible in storyboard.

Comment: If you create a button with only with code, it will never be visible in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can't see the button in your storyboard. The FBSDKLoginButton is a custom button provided by Facebook. By using the FBSDKLoginButton, you bypass some extra code. It is possible to add a custom login button in the storyboard and use to code from the Facebook developers docs within the button's connected action.

Answer (score 0):

Dan L is right. You can only manipulate and see objects in Storyboard that was added via the storyboard itself. However, you can see the `UIButton` that you added programmatically to the `ViewController` by viewing it in the View Debugger. This way you can rotate, zoom in, and focus on any element on the visible screen, even the Facebook Button. But this does not allow you to manipulate the objects within the view debugger. And most of the time you want to do that to set your auto layout constraints in relation to everything else on screen. You actually can *still* do this: but it requires a little imagination.

**1)** You must choose the elements in the view controller's storyboard (`IBOutlets`) that you want the button to be anchored to.

**2)** *In code*, **mentally visualize** where you'd want the `UIButton` to go. And for *each direction* of the button programmatic add NSLayoutConstraints to the surrounding views.

```
UIView *leftView = self.viewToTheLeftOfWhereIWantTheButtonToGo; //IBOutlet. Remember to list here all of the surrounding views like so
UIView *button = self.theFacebookButton; //IBOutlet
//Top | do for each direction
[container addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft  //button's Left
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:leftView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight  //leftView's Right
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:kFacebookButtonPadding]]; //some CGFloat you define

// And do this for Left, Bottom, and Right also.
```

**3)** Because all of the subviews including the Facebook button are subviews to the `self.view`, tell the main view to layout it's subviews.

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

**4)** Tweak this to your needs, Build and Run, and examine your results in the View Debugger. And that is the next best thing to using storyboards.